# Nginx/Node.JS - start Nginx only after node server is fully up

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker

How can I configure `nginx` systemd service to start only after a `node.js` server is fully started.

I have an ubuntu server with 1 CPU and 5 systemd services:

1. `nginx_dashboard.service`
2. 4 X `dashboard_customer@.service`

all services run at startup and all are running `docker` containers. Only the `nginx` container is exposed outside and it is the one that links to the 4 `node` applications.

The problem is that because of the 1 CPU and all services are starting together, it takes a few seconds for the `node` applications to start (10-13 seconds) while the much lighter `nginx` starts immediately.
I tried adding `Requires` and `After` to the nginx service, but it doesn't help since the node services are running, but the app itself inside the containers takes time to load.

In case the `nginx` is down, my content delivery system (in this case - CloudFlare), knows to present a temp page. But because of this delay, the nginx is up and I have a few seconds of downtime to my dashboard.

The question is if I can prevent this delay and start nginx only after the node.js application is fully up, not just the docker container.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `/healthz` route for checking if the app is ready. IN your nginx service, you can recursively check if the app is ready (`/healthz` returns http status code 200) and only start once it's ready.

Comment: How can I configure `nginx` to do health checks before starting?

Comment: @TomG you have to edit nginx service file and add that logic yourself.

Comment: the health check option in the nginx configuration is only available in the nginx plus program and not in the open source project